# Is there performance impact of using `map() + stream()` vs `flatMapMany() + map()`?

Tags: java, java-stream, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Is there difference in performance between using `map() + stream()` and `flatMapMany() + map()`?

For example, we have a collection of some entities and we need to map it to another representation of these objects:

```java
List<Entity> list = ... // init some collection
Mono.just(collection)
  .map(collection -> collection.stream.map(mapper::map))
  .flatMapMany(Flux::fromStream)
```

OR

```java
List<Entity> list = ... // init some collection
Mono.just(collection)
  .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
  .map(mapper::map)
```

In my opinion, Stream.map operations are more lightweight than Flux.map and allocate fewer objects, so then the first solution is better, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: have you tried to do some benchmarking?

Comment: The second would appear to have less statements.  The first closure, I imagine, is more exhaustive than the single _mapper::map_ call.

Comment: So the question, I guess, is Reactor good for a pure number crunching app? It works fine such an app, the difference is in ~5% from what I've seen, and twice easier to code. But if the app has a mix of IO and number crunching, that's a completely different story and that's what you should look at.

Comment: Why do you emphasize the initialization of `list` when you don’t use it at all? Do you actually mean `Mono.just(list)`? But what’s the point of wrapping the `Flux.fromIterable(…)` call in the `Mono` operation? Why not just use `Flux.fromIterable(list) .map(mapper::map)`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should choose from those two.

It depends on which task is executed by your mapper.

If there will be some blocking or long executed operation which you have wrapped with Mono - the best one will be:

```
List<Entity> list = ... // init some collection
Flux.fromIterable(list)
    .map(mapper::map)
    ...
```

Whether you worry about objects count, you can use Stream.map on list itself:

```
List<Entity> list = ... // init some collection
List<Entity> processedEntities = list.stream().map(mapper::map).toList();
```

It is on your consideration which one to choose, I can only assume that you still have to return some Mono/Flux from your method, so you will not achieve many benefits from those redundant steps.

Speaking about two examples you've provided, its looks like incorrect usage, since it makes redundant conversion from Mono to Flux